# Play / Stop Button

Tags: matlab, audio, playback

I have 2 callback functions, one plays the audio, the other stops the audio.

```
function Play_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global path;
global player;
[Y, Fs] = audioread(path);
player = audioplayer(Y,Fs);
play(player);
pause(max(size(Y))/Fs);

function Stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global player;
stop(player);
```

The problem is, that in the play callback, if I dont put the pause, nothing plays. The reason is that once the callback finishes, the 'player' variable is dumped. The pause however gives the chance for the audio to run it's course. The stop callback works too i.e. the audio is stopped. However the pause would still be ongoing when the track is stopped.

I want a solution that lets me use the rest of the functions, while the audio is being played and that doesnt require the pause to keep on going even after the stop button is clicked.

Any ideas?

EDIT, I tried another approach but still have a problem:
Play callback

```
global path;
[Y, Fs] = audioread(path);
player = audioplayer(Y,Fs);
guidata(handles.Play,player);
play(player);
```

Stop callback

```
player = guidata(hObject);
stop(player);
```

The problem is that when I try to choose another track from the uitable, I get an error on a line that enables another button

```
set(handles.getCandidatesByKey,'Enable','on');
```

and the error is:

```
No appropriate method, property, or field getCandidatesByKey for class audioplayer.
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to share data between callbacks. One simple way is to store your player variable in UserData field of hObject. For this to work you should also add a tag property when creating your play button. It is as simple as adding the following parameter, value pair when creating the button.

```
button = uicontrol(...
    'Tag','play_button',...
...);
```

In Play_Callback after creating audioplayer you should add the following line to store player variable.

```
hObject.UserData = player;
```

In Stop_Callback you can get this data back using

```
h = findobj('Tag','play_button');
player = h.UserData
```

You can find other ways of sharing data in the documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html

Comment: how can i do the first part ie. where you are creating the button.. but since Im using guide I want to set that tag in the create function. how can I do that?

Comment: Right click on the button and select property inspector. You should be able to see Tag as one of the options.

Comment: So in the play callback Im doing this: 
[Y, Fs] = audioread(path);
player = audioplayer(Y,Fs);
hObject.UserData = player;
play(player);

In the stop callback Im doing this:

h = findobj('Play');
player = h.UserData;

stop(player);

When trying to play a track I am getting this warning and the track is not playing:

Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See MATLAB R14SP2 Release Notes,
Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures Displays Warning, for details. 

What am I doing wrong? the tag of the play button is 'Play' btw.

Comment: That is a old release. Check the doc for that release for sharing data. http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R14sp2/techdoc/creating_guis/ch_program3.html. UserData might not be available in that release. I assume you are using R14SP2 release.

Comment: I do not have access to that document, is it the same as this??http://www.mn.uio.no/astro/english/services/it/help/mathematics/matlab/rn.pdf 

I now tried to use guidata (please see edited original question for callback code) .. and it worked. but as soon as I tried to click on another item from the uitable I got an error on this line: set(handles.getCandidatesByKey,'Enable','on');

The error was: No appropriate method, property, or field getCandidatesByKey for class audioplayer.

Can you suggest something to fix this problem??